# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, slim

I pass my request from Android

```
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request()->getBody();
$final = json_decode($request);
echo '{"test": ' . $final->name . '}';
```

where,

```
$request = "{\"name\":\"xxxx\"}"
```

while running it gives **Trying to get property of non-object** error message

Comment: Try echo'ing the content of: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: the example that you have provided is working like a charm, i think that you have a problem in another case... just `var_dump($request)` before you decoding it ans you will see the answer to your issue

Comment: @HalayemAnis I tried to pass static data in $request='{\"name\":\"xxxx\"}' it was working fine.. The problem I faced here double quote

Comment: @No_Rulz give me a `var_dump($request)` this will avoid us to guess the real problem :)

Comment: @HalayemAnis I got ""{\"name\":\"Durai\"}""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've encoded the object twice (the backslashes make me think that). So, decoding the object twice may fix this:

```
$final = json_decode(json_decode( $request ));
```

Or, don't encode twice in the first place. You could also strip the slashes and then decode.

Comment: "{\"name\":\"xxxx\"}" comes from Android which is JSONObject.toString value